# Passing Class object as Global Param

Tags: python, oop, typeerror, object-reference, function-parameter

I'm trying to pass a class object as an argument to a global function.

Here's the function:

```
def CreatePlayers(p1_Name, p2_Name, cardDeck):
  #Function to Create Players
  #Takes 3 variables: Names of player 1 and player 2 and the card deck
  #Returns a List of players [p1,p2]
  print("Creating Players... \n")
  print(f"Dealing a deck of ", len(cardDeck), " among 2 players")
  player1 = Player(p1_Name)
  player2 = Player(p2_Name)
  #Share cards between players
  for i in range(25):
    player1.addCard(cardDeck.dealOne())
    player2.addCard(cardDeck.dealOne())
  print("Verify... player creation\n")
  print(player1)
  print(player2)
  return [player1, player2]
```

The class object here's "cardDeck", and the class object is initialized before making the function call with the variable name, of course

And here's the class definition:

```
class Deck:
  '''A Python Deck class. Holds a list of Card objects 
     Possesses the following
        * Attributes: - myDeck (A list of cards. Expected = 50 cards in deck)
                      
        * Methods:    - Constructor (creates list)
                      - Shuffle
                      - Deal a card
                      - return number of cards
  '''
  def __init__(self):
    '''Method to initialize a deck'''
    self.myDeck = []
    #initialize cards
    for rank in Ranks:
      for order in Orders:
        self.myDeck.append( Card(order, rank) )
  
  ##other functions....
    
  def __len__(self):
    '''Return the size of the card deck'''
    return len(self.myDeck)
```

This is where I call my createPlayer() function:

```
myDeck = Deck().shuffle()
#Create my players
players = CreatePlayers("Adam", "Bob", myDeck)
```

And finally here's the error that I keep getting while running the 'createPlayer' function

> ```
> File "/home/CardGame.py", line 32, in CreatePlayers
>     print(f"Dealing a deck of ", len(cardDeck), " among 2 players")
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
> ```

Comment: So where is the argument to `CreatePlayer` defined? This doesn't really have anything to do with passing arguments, only how `cardDeck` came to have the value `None` in the first place.

Comment: Exactly @chepner. You need to add the driver function code - the one that is calling `CreatePlayers()` and where `cardDeck` is being constructed.

Comment: Just added that

Comment: `Deck().shuffle()` apparently doesn't *return* the deck; it shuffles it in place and returns `None` (as is conventional for mutating methods in Python).

Comment: `d = Deck(); d.shuffle(); players = CreatePlayers("Adam", "Bob", d)`

Comment: alright, forgot "shuffle()" is a generator function. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Deck().shuffle()` doesn't return the deck

you can do this to solve it :

```
myDeck = Deck(); 
myDeck.shuffle(); 
players = CreatePlayers("Adam", "Bob", myDeck)
```

an other alternative is to change shuffle to be a class method :

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    @classmethod
    def shuffle(cls):
        new_deck = cls()
        # Do shuffle here for new_deck
        return new_deck
```

and use it that way :

```
myDeck = Deck.shuffle(); 
players = CreatePlayers("Adam", "Bob", myDeck)
```

but that way you can't shuffle an existing deck so it depend on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, someone already informed me of that in the comment section